# Time conversion from hh:mm:yy (24 hour) to expanded time form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular-UI time plugin and so I need to convert a simple time format to a more complex one, i.e,

from:

```
16:19:29
```

to:

```
Wed Dec 09 2015 16:09:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Or if possible complete data from this format:

```
"2015-12-17 16:19:29"
```

Which I am receiving from json.

I need to know any javascript function exists that converts our simple time format to the expanded form (day month year is ***not important***, I can handle that!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this demo

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Please Rate if it helps</title>
    <script>
        Date.prototype.myFormat = function (start) {
            var temporeryDay = this.getDate();
            var temporeryMonth = this.getMonth() + 1;
            var temporeryYear = this.getFullYear();
            var temporeryHours = this.getHours();
            var temporeryMinutes = this.getMinutes();
            var temporerySeconds = this.getSeconds();
            temporeryDay = temporeryDay.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + temporeryDay.toString() : temporeryDay.toString();
        temporeryMonth = temporeryMonth.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + temporeryMonth.toString() : temporeryMonth.toString();
            temporeryHours = temporeryHours.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + temporeryHours.toString() : temporeryHours.toString();
            temporeryMinutes = temporeryMinutes.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + temporeryMinutes.toString() : temporeryMinutes.toString();
            temporeryHours = temporeryHours.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + temporeryHours.toString() : temporeryHours.toString();
            temporerySeconds = temporerySeconds.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + temporerySeconds.toString() : temporerySeconds.toString();
            return (temporeryYear + "-" + temporeryMonth + "-" + temporeryDay + " " + temporeryHours + ":" + temporeryMinutes + ":" + temporerySeconds);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            document.write(new Date().myFormat());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this simple [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/1j8bca5w/)

```
var timeStr = "16:19:29";
var timeStrArr = timeStr.split( ":" );

var date = new Date();
date.setHours( parseInt( timeStrArr[ 0 ] ) );
date.setMinutes( parseInt( timeStrArr[ 1 ] ) );
date.setSeconds( parseInt( timeStrArr[ 2 ] ) );

alert( date );
```